# Display p-values under 0.1 in r stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I have regression coefficients at p-value 0.06. The output table of stargazer does not display the dot (.) signalling p-values under 0.1. How do I make stargazer to signal p-values below 0.1 in the output table?

*It would be hard to find or create a reproducible example with p-values above 0.05 and below 0.1. If needed, I'll try and find something. But hopefully this is a softball question with a quick solution.

Comment: You can do it with the argument `star.cutoffs = c(.1, .05, .01)` or whichever levels you prefer. If you need to set the symbols, you can use the argument `star.char = c(".", "*", "**")` to specify the symbol corresponding to each significance level.

Comment: This worked, thanks. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Please note, when using this solution - which works - you need to adjust the note that appears at the bottom of the table, using the notes = c("+ p<0.1; * p<0.05; ** p<0.01; *** p<0.001") attribute and setting notes.append=FALSE"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with the `star.cutoffs` and `star.char` arguments. Some fake data below to demonstrate:

```r
library(stargazer)

# Generate some fake data
set.seed(10)
x <- rnorm(10)
x1 <- rnorm(10)
e <- rnorm(10)
y <- 10 + x + 2*x1 + e

# Estimate a model
m1 <- lm(y~x + x1)

# We can see that we have three different levels of sig at typical cutoffs
summary(m1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x + x1)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -1.12552 -0.20126 -0.06919  0.60370  0.76845 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)   9.1012     0.3731  24.394 4.95e-08 ***
#> x             0.8389     0.3923   2.138   0.0698 .  
#> x1            1.7477     0.4094   4.269   0.0037 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.7851 on 7 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.8167, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7643 
#> F-statistic: 15.59 on 2 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.002639

# We will make the 10% level a plus sign, and stars for .05, .01 and .001
stargazer(m1, type = "text",
          star.char = c("+", "*", "**", "***"),
          star.cutoffs = c(.1, .05, .01, .001))
#> 
#> ===============================================
#>                         Dependent variable:    
#>                     ---------------------------
#>                                  y             
#> -----------------------------------------------
#> x                             0.839+           
#>                               (0.392)          
#>                                                
#> x1                            1.748**          
#>                               (0.409)          
#>                                                
#> Constant                     9.101***          
#>                               (0.373)          
#>                                                
#> -----------------------------------------------
#> Observations                    10             
#> R2                             0.817           
#> Adjusted R2                    0.764           
#> Residual Std. Error       0.785 (df = 7)       
#> F Statistic            15.589** (df = 2; 7)    
#> ===============================================
#> Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Created on 2018-08-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Please note, when using this solution - which works - you need to adjust the note that appears at the bottom of the table, using the _notes = c("+ p<0.1; * p<0.05; ** p<0.01; *** p<0.001")_ attribute and setting _notes.append=FALSE"_